# How do you enable flash for Chromium running under Linux?

Tags: linux, chromium

I understand that the Linux builds of Chromium are still very alpha, but I'd like to enable the flash capabilities.

How do I get flash working in Chromium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, copy the flash plugin.

```
$ sudo cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins
```

Then start Chromium like this.

```
$ chromium-browser --enable-plugins
```

*This answer is outdated; you no longer need to do this to get flash running in Chromium.*

Comment: If you don't have a plugins directory under your chrome directory, making one seems to work.

Comment: There is no need for this painful hack in Debian: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7942... or at least not anymore.

Comment: Yes, Chromium isn't as "unstable" and as much of an development version as it is for normal usage at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome supports flash (and plugins generally) in recent builds. It was featured on [lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com/5327102/linux-chrome-builds-get-plug+in-support) not so long ago with links to repositories.

*They are experiencing some technical diffuculties, the site is slow and more down than up. I am happy that I managed to copy the url from the search results.*

Comment: OP was using Chromium, not Chrome.